# zsh alias open chrome with localhost port

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh

I am trying to create an alias in my zsh aliases to open Chrome with localhost:9292 being the URL. How would I go about adding the localhost and the port? I have it working where it adds the application for my alias, but won't open correctly. Here is what I have:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOs/Google\ Chrome --port=9292
```

When I do this I get an error

```
segmentation fault
```

Could someone who has done this before help me to understand how I can run my alias

```
alias devdocs="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOs/Google\ Chrome"
```

along with the localhost and port being loaded?

Thank you,

Rob

Comment: have you tried just passing the URL `http://localhost:9292` as argument?

Answer (score 4):

`open http://localhost:9292` if chrome is your default browser or

`open http://localhost:9292 -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app` if not.

Or write a function that takes a port

```html
function lh() { 
 if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  open http://localhost:3000
 else
  open http://localhost:$1
 fi
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. All the documentation around profiles and adding aliases that I found was too abstract. This answer provides just the right entry way for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of the following:

i) open http://localhost:9292 on an already opened chrome window

```
alias devdocs='open -a "Google Chrome" http://localhost:9292'
```

ii) open http://localhost:9292 on a new window

```
alias devdocs='open -a "Google Chrome" --args --new-window http://localhost:9292'
```

iii) if chrome is your default web browser

```
alias devdocs='open http://localhost:9292'
```

Check out [this article](https://jun711.github.io/productivity/how-to-open-websites-on-a-web-browser-using-a-command-on-mac/) for more information.